# Select where json field equals

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a JSON column in mysql. I am trying to query using one of its attributes as comparison value.

The query I'm trying to do would looks like this in mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM event
WHERE body->"$.item.id" = 651;
```

My problem is that doctrine fails to understand this. So I decided to extend it using a custom function:

The extension looks like this:

```
namespace App\DoctrineExtensions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class JsonSearch extends FunctionNode
{
    private string $column;
    private string $fieldPath;
    private string $operand;
    private string $operator;

    /**
     * @param Parser $parser
     * @throws QueryException
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->column = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->fieldPath = $parser->StringPrimary();
        // TODO: $this->fieldPath must mutch an [a-z]\. repeat pattern, no other chars to avoid injections.
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->operator = $parser->ComparisonOperator();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->operand = $parser->InputParameter();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return '(' . $this->column . '->"$.' . $this->fieldPath . '"' . $this->operator . $this->operand . ')';
    }
}
```

I would like the call to look like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('event');
$queryBuilder->from(Event::class, 'event');
$queryBuilder->where('JSONSEARCH(event.body, item.id, =, :value) = 1');
$queryBuilder->setParameter(':value', $value); // $value = 651
```

But I'm having multiple problems with this. First it treats item like an alias to something, and the value is not bound. I'm assuming that should not be a `StringPrimary` but I fail to find anything that match. I want to bind a simple string there. Not aliases, not anything fancy. A simple string, exactly as it comes. And obviously falls into my responsibility to ensure no injection is possible (the TODO part), but first I need to get it working.

How do I do this without using native query?

And since I feel this is one of those questions that will attract answers or comments like "why would you wanna do that", "why use mysql for jsons and not a mongo / something else?", etc.:

- I am aware of low performance over mysql jsons -> is not an issue
- I am aware I need to treat security -> is not complicated in this case
- I am aware there are better systems for data that is not normalized -> it would unnecessarily complicate the whole system for a single edge case
- I am aware I can use native queries -> I prefer defaulting to that only as a last resort

Comment: StringPrimary  isn't appropriate, I would use arithmeticPrimary, like in mysql findinset: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/FindInSet.php in general I think beberlei/doctrineextensions is a good thing to start from when writing a dql extension. also find_in_set is very similar to what you're doing, I'd say ;o) use the tools displayed there, let doctrine resolve what is meant by "event.body" and similar.

Comment: I tried with arithmeticPrimary (even before posting). Has the same issue. The problem is not with event.body since that is an actual column and can be mapped. The problem comes from item.id since that is something inside the body and cannot be mapped. Beberlei extensions are indeed a good place to start, but none of them are similar my case (at least none I checked) since all map actual columns / datasets. There is ofc a chance that I fail to grasp the case, if you think that is true can you pls. exemplify what you mean?

Comment: item.id probably really should be a string, I guess (in call I mean, so `JSONSEARCH(event.body, 'item.id', '=', :value) = 1`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was with the fact I was not calling the dispatch($sqlWalker). This happend because I typehinted attributes as string and values were converted semi-incorrectly to string (to be fair the doctrine code was missleading; if you go into the StringPrimary function and check the return type, string is there first so I thought it returns directly the string). The values are actually objects that at some point extend Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Node.

This allowed me to bind the path as param (still annoying that I need to do that but... could be worse).

I also ended up implementing JsonExtract for my needs, but JsonSearch should be similar. The code is below in case someone gets into a similar need. Maybe I'll create a lib with all json functions... seems that they are pretty scarce. Window functions even scarcer... not like they've been around for ages :)).

```
<?php

namespace App\DoctrineExtensions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\ASTException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Node;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class JsonExtract extends FunctionNode
{
    private Node $field;
    private Node $jsonPath;

    /**
     * @param Parser $parser
     * @throws QueryException
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->field = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->jsonPath = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    /**
     * @param SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     * @return string
     * @throws ASTException
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'JSON_EXTRACT(' . $this->field->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' . $this->jsonPath->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```